# PHP_EOL write to .txt file with $_POST

Tags: php, html

Failed to write correctly in existing text file..
Is there a way to display correctly the post values?
Thanks in advance.

```
$mar1 = $_POST['id'] . PHP_EOL;
$mar2 .= $_POST['titel'] . PHP_EOL;
$existing = file_get_contents('stan.txt');
$fp = fopen('stan.txt', 'w');    
$myString = '<h6><a href="$mar1-$mar2.php">$mar1 $mar2</a></h6>'. PHP_EOL; 
fwrite($fp, $existing. $myString);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: When you say *failed to write correctly* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: It says in the text file: <h6><a href="$mar1-$mar2.php">$mar1 $mar2</a></h6> instead of <h6><a href="value1-value2.php">value1 value2</a></h6>

Comment: Single quoted strings (as in `$myString`) are not subject to substitutions.